# Does `netstat` output different sockets with and without -n?

Tags: netstat

`man netstat` says

> --numeric, -n
>
> Show numerical addresses instead of trying to determine symbolic host,
>   port or user names.

Does `netstat` output additional sockets with `-n` than without `-n`?

Or does `netstat` output the same set of sockets with `-n` as without `-n`?

They don't seem to output the same set of sockets:

```
$ sudo netstat -ap | wc -l
720
$ sudo netstat -anp | wc -l
719
```

`-n` seems to output sockets not shown otherwise:

```
$ sudo netstat -ap | grep 2049
$ sudo netstat -anp | grep 2049
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2049            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::2049                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2049            0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp6       0      0 :::2049                 :::*
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely that one of the ports from the 720 list was simply removed in-between those runs; there should be no substantive difference in the *number of outputs* with or without `-n`.

You're seeing different output with the `grep 2049` because the `-n` flag specifically shows "**numerical addresses** instead of trying to determine symbolic host, **port names**"; if you had grepped for ":nfs" instead of "2049" in the second example, you would have seen corresponding results.